# p:commandButton vs. h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

When I am using a PrimeFaces `p:commandButton`

```
<p:commandButton action=#{bean.action} />
```

I don't see the the validation messages for inputs (both the default `h:` ones or the PrimeFaces `p:` ones.) For example with

```
<f:validateRequired />
```

When I am using default command button like

```
<h:commandButton action=#{bean.action} />
```

I do see the validations. What can be the cause of this difference?

I am using Prime Faces 3.5 with Mojarra 2.1.18

```
<h:form id="reliefhourheadcopy-form">

        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:outputText value="Kopiere Entlastungsstunden von" />
            <h:outputText value="Semester: #{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.reliefHourHead.semester}" />
            <h:outputText value="Jahr: #{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.reliefHourHead.year}" />
            <h:outputText value="nach" />               
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">

            <h:outputText value="Semester:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="semester" value="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.semester}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.semesterTypes}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message for="semester" />

            <h:outputText for="yearSpinner" value="Jahr:" />
            <p:spinner id="yearSpinner" value="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.year}" maxlength="4" min="2000" max="2030" size="4">
                <f:validateRequired />
                <f:validateLongRange minimum="2000" maximum="2030" />
            </p:spinner>
            <h:message for="yearSpinner" />

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-top:25px">
            <p:commandButton action="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.copyReliefHourHead}" value="Kopieren" icon="ui-icon-copy" >
                <f:param name="reliefhourhead_id" value="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.reliefHourHeadId}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Main difference is that `p:commandButton` is AJAX by default, and `h:commandButton` is non-AJAX by default. Post code for whole form. Maybe you just didn't updated validation messages field with primefaces button.

Comment: Add `update="@form"` to `p:commandButton` and see if error messages are shown.

Comment: Thanks partlov that was the hint I needed! update="@form" does the trick. But also ajax="false". If I use ajax="false" also <h:messages /> is updated correctly. Regards caron.

Comment: Yes, in that case with non-AJAX request button will act as `h:commandButton`.

Comment: @parlov: do you want to create an answer with all this info in it? The upvoted answer is not that good in explaining things. Otherwise I'd like to write an answer with all details in it.

Answer (score 7):

Like @Partlov wrote in the comments below the question,

> Main difference is that p:commandButton is AJAX by default, and h:commandButton is non-AJAX by default.

So

```
<p:commandButton ... />
```

is more like

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax/>
</h:commandButton>
```

but

```
<p:commandButton ...>
    <p:ajax/>
</p:commandButton>
```

is wrong and leads to undefined behaviour

or the other way around

```
<h:commandButton ... />
```

is like

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" ... />
```

The `p:commandButton` will submit the form by default. However by default it does not update anything in the form after the ajax call is finished so the messages are not displayed (which in development mode would have shown in the log files that messages were enqueued but not displayed) . The non-ajax `h:commandButton` does a full page refresh that does show the messages. In order to get the form (which contains the message component) updated when using the `p:commandButton` you need to add the `update` attribute:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.copyReliefHourHead}" value="Kopieren" icon="ui-icon-copy" update="@form">
    <f:param name="reliefhourhead_id" value="#{reliefHourHeadManagedBean.reliefHourHeadId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Adding an (superfluous) `f:ajax` or `p:ajax` inside a `p:commandXXX` can result in strange undefined behaviour

**See also**

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Comment: It will submit whole form, it just will not update whole form.

Comment: You mean that this would happen without putting the update? If this is the case I will edit my answer.

Comment: With update you control which parts are updated, with process you control what is submitted. With this update you update form (with messages, so the messages will be visible). Without update you just will not see messages.

Comment: Thank you, before I used to mix update and process in primefaces! I will edit this answer.