# Primefaces commandButton not updating datatable. Is update attribute required

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I changed my `<h:commandButton>` tag to a PrimeFaces `<p:commandButton>` tag on a search page and my datatable stopped displaying the results.  After adding an `update` attribute things worked again. I'm just trying to understand whether it is how I implemented the overall functionality (viewscope, action vs actionListener, etc) or is the `update` attribute really required?

```xhtml
<h:form id="search_form">
    <p:inputText id="search" value="#{searchBean.searchString}" />
    <p:commandButton update="search_form" value="Search" action="#{searchBean.searchByString}" >
    </p:commandButton>

<p:dataTable id="output" var="res" value="#{searchBean.results}" emptyMessage="No results found with given criteria">

etc...
```

```java
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class SearchBean {

@Inject
private SearchRepository searchRepository;
private List<Results> res;
private String searchString; 

public SearchBean() {
        }

public String searchByString()
{
    this.setRes(searchRepository.searchBySingleString(searchString));
}
```

Comment: The `update` attribute is required for the change to be visible by the client (UA).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the differences between `h:commandButton` and `p:commandButton` is that the second one performs an ajax request by default, while the first executes a plain *POST* request.

In an ajax request, you must specify what you want to process when form is sent and what to update when response happens. The `p:commandButton` updates nothing by default, that's why your table is not being properly filled.

**See also:**

- [Prime Faces Command Button vs. Default Command Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267958/prime-faces-command-button-vs-default-command-button)
- [Primefaces commandButton](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml)