# Calling p:dialog using JSF commandbutton/button doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:button value="SHOW" onclick="PF('myPanel').show()" />

    <p:dialog header="MyPanel" widgetVar="myPanel">
            <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Clicking the button only flashes the dialog -- opens and immidiatelly closes it. Also tried using JSF commandButton with same result. Using a primefaces button works as expected, so what is JSF button missing here?

Comment: JSF button and commandButton submit form (and refresh page), primefaces button not (AJAX action is called).

Comment: Learn what an `h:button` and `h:commandButton` exactly do, their differences and usage. And try to read some articles and/or Q/A about debugging. And btw a panel !=dialog and you don't **call** a dialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prime Faces Command Button vs. Default Command Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267958/prime-faces-command-button-vs-default-command-button)

Comment: JSF is a real deep hole for ones who never worked with basic HTML/JavaScript before. I recommend you to take a JSF pause and practice a bit more with basic JTML/JS. There are good tutorials at http://htmldog.com.

Answer (score 0):

use `<p:commandButton>` instead.

```
<p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
```